# Qt Windows application to open console output

Tags: c++, qt, shell, qtgui, qtcore

I have a Windows application that I want to run some ant scripts from the console/command line.  What I would like to do is click on my execute button and open a console/shell window and run the command on windows, unix, mac and exit when its done.  This way I can see all the output.  I've been using QProcess to do it and it works.  But I really want to open a console window every time I run the script. Is their an API that I can use to do this?

**Update**

Here is my code:

```
QString argument = QString("ant -f %1 %2 %3\n\r").arg(QDir::cleanPath(file), parameter, target);
QProcess scriptProcess;
scriptProcess.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);

if (Commons::GetCurrentOSID() == 1) // Windows
    scriptProcess.start(QString("cmd"));
else if (Commons::GetCurrentOSID() == 2) // Mac
    scriptProcess.start(QString("bash"));
else if (Commons::GetCurrentOSID() == 3)
    scriptProcess.start(QString("bash")); // Windows

if (!scriptProcess.waitForStarted())
{
    message.append("Ant command failed to execute");
}
else
{
    scriptProcess.write(argument.toStdString().c_str());
    scriptProcess.write("exit\n\r");

    result = scriptProcess.waitForFinished();
    if (result == false)
    {
        message.append("Ant command failed to complete");
    }
    else
        result = true;
}

scriptProcess.closeWriteChannel();
QByteArray output = scriptProcess.readAll();
text->setPlainText(output);
```

***Note:***  Make sure you have your ant, java, etc settings set in the environment.

Comment: Why do you need a console windows instead of just a GUI element, like QLabel or QTextEdit (read-only)?

Comment: Basically I want to run for example the following command:
ant -f build.xml -Dproject=something do something
Then let it just output all the information on the console.  Ive used QProcess but it seems like on long output it doesnt show everything.

Comment: In some instances QProcess doesnt seem to catch all the output.  And some instances it seems the same ant scripts that works on the console fails when running in QProcess.  And i wonder if its because the ant script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I would personally use:

```
QProcess scriptProcess;
scriptProcess.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
scriptProcess.start("ant", QStringList{"-f", "build.xml", "-Dproject=something"});
if (!scriptProcess.waitForStarted())
    return false;

if (!scriptProcess.waitForFinished())
    return false;

QByteArray output = scriptProcess.readAll();
myLabel.setText(output);
```

Make sure you use shebang and so on properly, otherwise, you might need to specify the interpreter explicitly.

Comment: Hmm, I will give this a try and see what happens.  Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by shebang?

Comment: This works great Thanks.  The problem i was seeing is that ant kicks off other process which failed because i only set the environment using qputenv which isnt system wide but once i set the ant environment on on path it all worked. Again thank you